# What files do you have to be aware of when migrating (i.e config files)?

Tags: config, migration

What files do you have to be aware of when migrating a craft application from one domain to another? Are the specific files one should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Most craft installs will require moving the database and asset folders, since these are typically not checked into version control. If the site is in version control, it should be a simple clone to install in a new domain.

Comment: To add to this Craft 3's .env file will need to be configured.